# returning the sum of a users input until they say stop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create something that constantly takes a users input until they say stop. Then, add all of the previous numbers together. This is what I have so far:

```
arr = []

puts "Give me a number:"
while input = gets.chomp
  if input == "stop"
    break
  else
    puts "Give me a number:"
    arr << input
  end
end

sum = arr.inject(:+)
puts sum
```

This is working fine up until adding the numbers together. The arr.inject(:+) seems to be joining the numbers together rather than adding.

For example, when in the while loop, I am entering 1, 2 and 3 into the gets.chomp, but the program is returning 123 rather that 6.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The numbers from `gets` aren't numbers, they're strings :) Add a `to_i` e.g. `arr << input.to_i`

Comment: @mikej Or `arr.sum(&:to_i)`.

Comment: (Although if their Ruby is new enough for that, then they could just do `input.to_i` and `.sum`. But I like `.sum(&:...)` so much :-)

Comment: sum is a Rails function, it is not in plain ruby. https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum

Comment: @Juan [au contraire](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: @SagarPandya oh yeah they added it in ruby 2.4.0....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.inject(0) { |sum,e| sum + e.to_i }
```

a bit more verbose but your problem is that reading from input == String and you want Integer.

Other solution could be

```
arr.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
```

But the first one is more efficient but less fancy.

Answer (score 1):

It is the combination of

```
arr << input
```

and

```
arr.inject(:+)
```

For example, if you change the first one to:

```
arr << input.to_i
```

then it would not be wrong any more.